# Some values are null in my render_to_response dictionary

Tags: python, django

I've been fighting with this for a few days now and I'm stumped. At the top of my function in views.py I setup an empty dictionary:

```
variables = {}
```

Through out my function, I add values to the dictionary

```
line: 710: variables['isolate_location'] = True
...
line 715: variables['show_request_list']= False
..
line 748: variables['servicerecords'] = service_records_list
..    
line 809: variables['form'] = service_record_form
..
..
..
    return render_to_response('locations/location_servicerecords.html', variables,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

No, when my template loads 3 of the 4 values I listed above come out null (lines 710, 715, & 809). I'm simply using them in if statments o my template. I have even set variables['show_request_list']= True right before my return (as a test), and it still comes out as null.

Here is a section of my template:

```
{% if user.is_staff %} {# The add button, ensures add button visible only when user has permission #}
    <a href="{% url 'admin:locations_servicerecord_changelist' %}?q={{ location.id }}" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Admin</a>
    <a href="{% url 'location_servicerecords' location.id %}?show_records=1&show_requests=0" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Service Records</a>
    {% if isolate_location == True %}
        <a href="{% url 'location_servicerecords' location.id %}?show_records=0&show_requests=1" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Service Requests</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if show_request_list == False %}
        <a href="#addServiceRecord" role="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target=""><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Service Record</a>
    {% elif show_request_list == True %}
        <a href="#addServiceRequest" role="button" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target=""><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Service Request</a>
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Any ideas on how I can debug this? Let me know if you need more information.

UPDATE: My if statements in my template have been sorted out. However, some dictionary values are still coming up empty. Here is a key one:

variables['show_request_list'] from above is being set to either true or false based on a query strings value:

```
if request.GET.get('show_requests', ''):
        show_requests = int(request.GET.get('show_requests'))
if show_requests==1:
        variables['show_request_list']= True
```

By default variables['show_request_list'] is set to false.

I use that variables template to display variables['servicerequests'], which is build as shown below:

```
 cur_loc_active_service_reqs = ServiceRequest.objects.filter(location=location_id).order_by(
        '-request_made_date')

    #Pagination
    service_requests_paginator = Paginator(cur_loc_active_service_reqs, RECORDS_PER_PAGE)  # Show 25 contacts per page

    try:
        service_request_list = service_requests_paginator.page(service_request_page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        if service_request_id:
            service_request_page = cur_loc_active_service_reqs.filter(service_date__gt=cur_service_rec.service_date).count()/RECORDS_PER_PAGE+1
        else:
            service_request_page = 1
        service_request_list = service_requests_paginator.page(service_request_page)
    except EmptyPage:  # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        service_request_list = service_requests_paginator.page(service_requests_paginator.num_pages)


    if service_request_list:
        variables['servicerequests'] = service_request_list
```

variables['servicerequests'] should have at least one record it in as there are values in my DB. When I try and render both {{ servicerequests }} & {{ show_request_list }} nothing shows up.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You said you are using these in `if` statements, what happens if you just try to render the value, e.g `{{ isolate_location }}` or `{{ form }}`? Can you show your template code?

Comment: #WeNeedToSeeYourCode

Comment: And *where exactly* is that initial declaration? Do you mean it's at the very top of the file, outside of any actual view functions?

Comment: @Joseph when I try to render the values nothing is rendered at all.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, sorry (original post updated). The initial declaration is at the top of my function.

Comment: @Joseph specifically with the {{ form }}  i get the following error: BootstrapError: Parameter "form" should contain a valid Django Form. Previously before my updates to the code form worked fine. My latest update to the code was just building the variables dictionary with more values.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not what you think it is. It is simply that `True` and `False` are not automatically present in the template context, so (as with any other nonexistent template variables) they default to None, and your comparisons fail.

However there is no reason to be explicitly comparing with those values anyway. As with Python code, you should simply do a boolean test:

```
{% if isolate_location %}
    ...
{% endif %}
{% if not show_request_list %}
    ...
{% elif show_request_list %}
    ...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks. That did help with my checks. Some of my other dictionary values like form are still coming up as nothing.  Am I declaring things correctly in my function?

Comment: Please show where form is coming from in the first place.

Comment: Ok i figured out my form. I"m going to update the original post with one other other dictionary values I"m struggling with. Thanks Daniel

Comment: Any thoughts? Does my code make sense or is there anything else I can provide?

Comment: I'm starting to get the follow error. Does my error and my initial question relate: TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str - its being thrown against my variables = {} I'm really stumped